# Rank of normal closure of a subset

Tags: gr.group-theory

How does one find the rank of a normal closure of a subset?

In particular, I am studying this group: Let $K_n$ be the group with $n$ generators $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ satisfying the relation that each $x_i$ commutes with all its conjugates, where $i=1,\cdots,n$. Thus there is a group homomorphism $f_{n}:K_n\to K_{n-1}$ mapping $x_i$ to $x_i$ when $i\leq n$ and maps $x_n$ to the identity element. Consider the kernel of $f$: it is the conjugate closure of the one-element subset $\{x_n\}$ of $K_n$. Then what is the rank (I mean the minimum number of generators) of the normal closure of $\{x_n\}$?

Comment: Is *conjugate closure* the same as *normal closure*?

Comment: Yes, they are exactly the same.

Comment: As stated the rank of the normal closure of $\{ x_n \}$ in $K_n$ could be 1 if $K_n$ is abelian and infinite if $K_n$ is the free group. Do you also mean that $x_i$ only commutes with elements it is conjugate to?

Comment: @NeilHoffman, Yes, $K_n$ is neither Abelian (unless $n=1$) nor the free group. In $K_n$, each generator $x_i$ commutes with all the conjugates of $x_n$. When $n=2$, it is the discrete Heisenberg group.